# Redhat Kickstart Multiple Harddrive (Virtualbox Implementation)

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, hard-drive

I am setting up a kickstart server using Apache Server. I followed this [tutorial](http://modlearning.com/linux/building-a-kickstart-server-centos-5/) and everything works fine there.  However I am writing the ks.cfg file trying to mount separate disk into separate partitions beyond of that post scope. Say I have 10 disks, and I want to use the first disk maybe as /root, /boot, swap..etc. And /dev/sdb mount to /data1, /dev/sdc mount to /data2...

I am testing it using virtual box but it doesn't like my ks.cfg file.

[image]

My `part` part looks like below:

```
# Wipe all partitions and build them with the info below
clearpart --all --drives=sda,sdb,sdc,sdd --initlabel
# Create the bootloader in the MBR with drive sda being the drive to install it on
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda,sdb,sdc,sdd
part /boot --fstype ext3 --size=100 --onpart=sda
part / --fstype ext3 --size=3000 --onpart=sda
part swap --size=2000 --onpart=sda
part /home --fstype ext3 --size=100 --grow
part /data1 --fstype=ext4 --onpart=sdb --grow --asprimary --size=200
part /data2 --fstype=ext4 --onpart=sdc --grow --asprimary --size=200
part /data3 --fstype=ext4 --onpart=sdd --grow --asprimary --size=200
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the part? Also, there is a sample [ks.cfg](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~ayounts/ks.cfg) that I reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem attempting to mount a second hard drive (sdb) during the install. What worked for me was to run the install the first time, then login to a root accessible account and format and partition the sdb drive. Afterwards, when re-installing the image, kickstart recognized and mounted sdb. Hope this helps.